# May I use latest pygobject for gtk2 with gobject introspection on windows?

Tags: glib, pygobject

I want my gtk2+python environment (on windows) support gobject instrospection.
It's all about glib, gobject introspection and pygobject libraries.
May I just replace the glib and related libraries to latest version?
I have downloaded some precompiled version of glib but the programs using old glib could not start anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had some success in the past using GTK 2 with GObject Introspection (on Linux), but it was unreliable. Don't do it.

There are official binaries of GTK 3 available for Windows, but you'll likely have to compile GObject Introspection yourself.